# Cannot keep logging enabled while svnserve is running

Tags: svn, svnserve

When I try to configure logging for svnserve, using the command:

```
$ svnserve -d -r /svn --log-file /var/log/svn.log
```

I receive the error `svnserve: Can't bind server socket: Address already in use`. After some research I ran `$ps -ef | grep svnserve` and killed the other process, which ended up just stopping svnserve. With svnserve stopped, executing the logging command does not give me an error. However I cannot restart svnserve after this, until killing the new process that is created by the logging setup command.

I am having trouble determining how to keep them running at the same time so that logging will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you issue `svnserve -d -r /svn --log-file /var/log/svn.log`, this will start the svnserve daemon with logging, you don't need to run any other svnserve command.